# How to get current displayed month in table_calendar package flutter

Tags: flutter, calendar, flutter-dependencies

I'm building a calendar using the table_calendar flutter package. Other all things are done now just I want to get currently selected month from the calendar. I try to find out the way and try all the events but did not get success yet. Anyone have a solution, help me a lot.

**Package Link: https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at https://pub.flutter-io.cn/documentation/table_calendar/latest/table_calendar/CalendarController-class.html

You should be able to get the current month by using `focusedDay` on the CalendarController.

```
focusedDay → DateTime
Currently focused day (used to determine which year/month should be visible).
read-only
```